# Need bash script output on one line - curl and >> produces 2 lines

Tags: bash, scripts

I am running this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S " | tr -d 'n' >> /home/test_a5gh/Pub_IP.txt
curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com?newline -s >> /home/test_a5gh/Pub_IP.txt
cat /home/test_a5gh/Pub_IP.txt
```

After creating the above file, I placed it in the folder `/home/test_a5gh/` and then I made the script executable:

```
$ sudo chmod u+x testip.sh
```

Next, to test the script, I ran:

```
$ ./testip.sh
```

However, the output of this command is being produced on 2 lines. Here is an example:

```
2011-22-33 16:10:27 
111.222.333.444
```

I need the output to appear on 1 line, like this:

```
2011-22-33 16:10:27 111.222.333.444
```

Additional Information:

The script is taken from [here](https://thomashunter.name/blog/scheduling-a-daily-cron-task-in-debian-to-check-external-ip/).

**Question:**

Is there a way to get this output on 1 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#!/bin/bash

mydate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
myip=$(curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com?newline -s)

printf '%s %s\n' "$mydate" "$myip" >> /home/test_a5gh/Pub_IP.txt
```

FYI, you don't need `sudo` to `chmod` files you own in your own home directory.

Comment: Hey, that is a great answer! It worked. Could you explain what changes you made?